# Does Orchard support some form of config transforms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, orchardcms

What is "the Orchard way" to define environment-specific configurations and/or configuration transforms? Is it possible to use regular Web.config transforms like in any other ASP.NET web app, or does Orchard have it's own engine for this?

(I've not been able to find any useful information on this topic in either the official docs or out in the wild.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to store that information in web.config, as in any other ASP.NET application. In lots of cases it's the only way to go (eg. environment-specific IIS settings and so on).

You may also store custom settings in Orchard database, by writing your custom settings part and attaching it to "Site" content type. It's the preferred way to go if you have some data to store, that does not have to be kept inside web.config file (alternative to creating a custom config section).

Comment: Ok but a simple example then; how would you specify different Orchard database connection strings per environment (local, test, production)? As a part of a custom deployment script, or in some kind of config transform in the actual solution?

Comment: Orchard connection strings and a few other settings (like database prefix for tables, encryption key etc.), are being kept in `AppData/Sites/<site name>/Settings.txt`. You may have a deployment script alter it depending on environment, or keep one file for each environment somewhere and copy the correct one during deployment.